# geth attach not finding ipc

Tags: go-ethereum

Running a private net and the logs are fine:

```
I0617 09:25:22.463133 node/node.go:298] IPC endpoint opened: /home/roland/privethnet/geth.ipc
```

but attaching does not work:

```
geth --ipcpath ~/privethnet/geth.ipc attach
Fatal: Unable to attach to geth: dial unix /home/roland/.ethereum/geth.ipc: connect: no such file or directory
```

What could be wrong?